Error at key 'web_accessible_resources'. Parsing array failed at index 0: expected dictionary, got string Could not load manifest
guys i try to change manifest_version 2 to 3 but they occur web_accessible_resource error
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "/app/nj.js",
  "/app/bg.js",
  "/manifest.json",
  "/img/icon-128.png",
  "/img/new-post-extra-tag-assist.png",
  "/img/new-post-extra-cover-assist.png",
  "/img/new-post-extra-music-assist.png",
  "/img/rocket.png",
  "/img/harpa-avatar.png"
]

}
error:
Error at key 'web_accessible_resources'. Parsing array failed at index 0: expected dictionary, got string
Could not load manifest.
